# How to loop through a 2d list/tuple in a certain order and user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a 2D list/tuple and loop through it BUT with user input, i mean it will advance 1 "block" of the list/tuple only when the user gives the input to.

Like:

1  4  7

2  5  8

3  6  9

So it would start in 1 by default but then the program should ask for user input to advance or not advance through the list and then display what is contained that section.

When the last number is reached (in this case 9) it would go back to the beginning and keep going indefinitely.

I have thinking about how to do this for hours and i just reached the conclusion that my programming knowledge is pretty basic to solve this on my own... sadly.

I'm just a beginner after all.

I have tried many things but i scratched everything, i am not seeing something here.

Comment: please share your efforts !

Comment: Kinda have it now but i have another question about this problem and i don't know if i should put the question on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop and a counter will work for this problem:

```
s = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
answer = "y"
count = 0
while answer == "y":
   if count == len(s):
      count = 0
   for i in s[count]:
       print(i)
   answer = input("Do you want to continue?")[0].lower()
   count += 1
```

Comment: I'm studying the code and it does what i want to do but only on each tuple it doesn't go through each one of the numbers, like first 1,4,7 etc. I have adapted it thoug to what i have before and it kinda does it. What does this part of your code mean: [0].lower()

Comment: @Hagogs I am not sure what you mean. The inner `for` loop will allow you transverse each list. `[0].lower()` is a more robust way of reading in user input. If the user enters `yes` or `y` or `Yes`, it will still allow the loop to run because we are only looking at the lowercase version of the first character.

Comment: I mean that the first result is 1,4,7 then 2,5,8 and so on and i just wanted to display 1 index each time, like first 1 then 4 then 7 for each time the user press y.